# Number of neuron in CNN architecture

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am using a certain CNN architecture, however, I am not sure how to calculate the exact number of neuron I have in it.

```
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=16,
                               kernel_size=(7, 7), padding=(1, 1),
                               stride=(2, 2))

        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32,
                               kernel_size=(7, 7), padding=(1, 1),
                               stride=(2, 2))

        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64,
                               kernel_size=(3, 3), padding=(2, 2),
                               stride=(2, 2))

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64 * 1 * 1, 8)
```

There is also `2D-maxpooling` after each `convolution layer` with stride of `2`.

I can get the number of parameters and Gmacs in my network, but I am not sure how to get the number of neurons?

Is there a certain way to calculate them?

Thanks.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/ Maybe you should first figure out what a "neuron" is? Also what do TF and keras have to do with your question?

Answer (score 1):

One quick way to get the total count is to

1. Fetch all parameters with [`nn.Module.parameters`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=nn%20module#torch.nn.Module.parameters);
2. Convert the generator to a flattened tensor with [`torch.nn.utils.parameters_to_vector`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.parameters_to_vector.html);
3. Find the total number of elements with [`torch.Tensor.numel`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.numel.html).

Which corresponds to:

```
>>> p2v(model.parameters()).numel()
44936
```

<sub>Having imported `parameters_to_vector` from `torch.nn.utils` as `p2v`</sub>

---

If you want to count the parameters yourself:

- Convolutions when counting kernels and biases. Given number of input channels `in_c`, output channels `out_c`, and kernel size `k`:

  ```
  conv = lambda in_c, out_c, k: k*k*in_c*out_c + out_c
  ```
- Fully-connected layers: just a two-dimensional matrix with biases:

  ```
  fc = lambda in_c, out_c: in_c*out_c + out_c
  ```
- Max-pool layers are non-parametrized layers: `0` parameters.

All in all, this gives you:

```
>>> conv(1, 16, 7) + conv(16, 32, 7) + conv(32, 64, 3) + fc(64, 8)
44936
```

---

The word *neurons* is just an abstraction. If you consider it to be the output dimension for each given layer then:

- For convolution layers, it will depend on the spatial dimension of the input. So given the spatial dimension `x`, the kernel size `k`, the padding `p`, and the stride `s`:

  ```
  conv = lambda x, k, p, s: math.floor((x+2*p - k)/ s + 1)
  ```
- For fully connected layers, it corresponds to the number of output features.

Comment: Hi Ivan,

Thanks a lot for your comment. Are you calculating the number of parameters in the network, or the number of neurons?

I am not really interested in the number of parameters, I need to get the number of neurons actually.

Thanks and looking forward to your response

Comment: What do you mean by *neurons* exactly?

Comment: The number of neurons (normally followed by activation functions) we have in the network! I think they should be the feature maps out of the convolution layers.

Comment: We are not defining specific neurons in the CNNs, but there should be neurons in it!!

And I think they are the size of the feature maps of each convolution layer, so simply the depth*width*height of each convolution and then of course the number of output neurons in the FC.

Comment: I don't see why *"there should be"*, *neuron* is just terminology to stick with the metaphor... In practice, there is no benefit in computing such quantity. Anyhow, I have edited my answer.